# How do i change the width of window inside the code?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Name="W_win_rp" Background="Bisque" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" d:DesignHeight="350" d:DesignWidth="525" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
```

How do i change this designwidth inside the code at runtime ?

Answer (score 3):

Design width and height are for design not runtime

for changing Window's Width and Height simply use
this.Width and this.Height

Comment: this is the first thing i tried and it doesn't works with d:DesignWidth

Comment: you can't change d:DesignWidth because it's for designtime

Comment: everything can be changed, i doubt that there is something that can't be done

Comment: Why you want to change this values?

Comment: i want to reduce width at runtime, nothing special